# If $F(x) = (3x -1)/2$ and $F^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$, then what is the value of $F^{-1}(3)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Another practice math placement test that has me curious.

> If $F(x) = (3x -1)/2$ and $F^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$, then what is the value of $F^{-1}(3)$?

The answer I wrote was $2/5$ but the correct answer is $7/3$.  I am so confused.

Comment: $7 \over 2$ or $7\over 3$?

Comment: If $F(x)=\frac{3x-1}{2}$ then $x = \frac{(3F^{-1}(x)-1)}{2}$.  Rearranging, we get $F^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x+1}{3}$.  Plugging in $3$ we get $\frac{7}{3}$

Comment: Sorry 7/3 is the correct answer

Comment: thank you.  This is over my head right now.

Comment: What part of it went over your head?  The reason why we replaced $F(x)$ by $x$ and replaced $x$ by $F^{-1}(x)$?  That is just an easily visualized technique which is taught for coming up with inverses.  Was what you got stuck with instead how to algebraically manipulate $x=\frac{3F^{-1}(x)-1}{2}$ in order to isolate $F^{-1}(x)$?  Do the following steps in order: multiply both sides by two, add one to both sides, divide both sides by three.

Comment: Swap $(x,y)$ Next $ 2y =3x-1 \, \rightarrow 2x=3y-1 \rightarrow y=(2x+1)/3 $ then plug in $x=3$

Comment: Well, I too the placement test last week and got math 28 calculus for business.  So I have to take one lower level class to get in the calculus track.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you plugged $3$ into $F$ and got $\frac{5}{2}$.  Then you took the reciprocal of that to get your answer.  But the superscript $-1$ doesn't me "multiplicative inverse", but "function inverse."

Asking what $F^{-1}(3)$ means finding what value of $a$ to plug into $F(x)$ to get $3$.  That is,  solve $F(a) = 3$.  So you need to solve the equation

$$\frac{3a-1}{2} = 3.$$

What you get for $a$ is the right answer.